# Visual Studio compile option is grayed out for a single cpp file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, linkage, vcxproj

I have been asked to help a colleague regarding a mysterious build error in one of the projects in a common solution. The build error happens in the linkage stage, a class constructor defined in a static lib (a.lib) is not found when it is used in a lib (b.lib) that includes that a.lib. After careful investigation I figured out that:

1. The constructor is correctly defined in the class.
2. The class is defined in a cpp file that belongs to the project.
3. If a try to navigate to the cpp file or the class constructor with intellisense everything goes as expected.

vcxproj file ClCompile ItemGroup:

```
...
<ClCompile Include="Source\CMYKOVBLab.cpp" />
<ClInclude Include="Source\CMYKOBGLab.cpp" />  <--- The file is here.
<ClCompile Include="Source\CMYKOVBRGB.cpp" />
...
```

In summary, what is needed to link the library is there, but the linkage error persists.

One strange thing I noticed is the fact that the cpp with the class constructor not found could not be compiled by hitting Ctrl-F7 or the right button in a.lib. That option is grayed out, but only for that particular file. Moreover, when I build the a.lib library where this file should be compiled, it is not, and therefore no object file is created.

[image: cpp file compilation not possible]

What can be the cause? How can I fix it?

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VS 2015 the compile include files defined in the .*vcxproj* project file are expected to be in **lexicographical order**.

This is no longer needed in VS 2017 but when it is not respected, VS 2015 can create this kind of chaos.

Your colleague has **modified manually** the .*vcxproj* project file to include that file, but he has not respect the lexicographical order. You need simply to **remove the file from the project** and **add it back again**. Visual Studio will include it in the **right place** and your build will succeed.

Hope this can help other people too.

Comment: Either modified it manually, or used git/svn. There is a rather nasty interaction between tools naively using `diff` on structured files, and Visual Studio 2015 using XML files with a rather restrictive interpretation on their format.

Comment: This may have fixed the problem, but the answer from @Eram below is the real reason why.  It will not be compiled if the tag (ClInclude instead of ClCompile) is wrong.  The fix just removed user error.

Answer (score 2):

Your source file could not be compiled because it was added to the .vcxproj file in a "ClInclude" element, which is for headers. Fix it to ClCompile either manually or by removing and readding it in Visual Studio, then it will compile.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The accepted answer may have worked for the user, but it's only because removing the file and adding it via the GUI prevented the wrong tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you use qt+visual studio,I found a bug in the vs qt plugin when manually dragging files in. The real reason is that if the qt plugin detects the `Q_OBJRCT` macro when adding a header file, it will use `QtMoc` to include the header file instead of `Cllnclude`, but it will probably fail.but Right-click add does not present this problem
如果你使用qt+visual studio，我发现一个bug在vs qt插件手动拖动文件时。真正的原因是，如果qt插件在添加头文件时检测到' Q_OBJRCT '宏，它将使用' QtMoc '来包含头文件而不是' cllninclude '，但它可能会失败。但是右键添加不会出现这个问题
[image]